# How to return an array as a list of Nodes

Tags: java, generics, nodes

So I'm working on this code where the user inputs an int array x into the method xify(x). Which should then return the amount of numbers of each element. So, if `x` is the array `[4, 2, 3]`, we should return the headed list: `4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3`.

However, it appears my method just returns an empty list. I cannot seem to track what's the problem. Below I provided my `xify()` method, as well as a helper method called add that would add the nodes to the list.

```
public static Node<Integer> xify(int[] x){
    Node<Integer> result = new Node<>(null, null);
    int counter=0;
    int length=x.length;
    while(counter<length){ //loop through the array
        while(x[counter]!=0){ //take each element, add it to the list * int of the elem
        add(result,x[counter]);
        x[counter]=x[counter]-1;}
        counter++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Helper Method:

```
 public static<T> void add(Node<T> list, T element){
     while(list.getNext()!=null){
         list=list.getNext();
     }
     list.setNext(new Node<>(element, null));
 }
```

What is wrong with my algorithm?

P.S As you may have seen, it is using Generics, as that is what I am currently learning.

How I am calling it:

```
System.out.println(xify(array));
System.out.println(toString(xify(array)));
```

Comment: i hope your problem is `add(result,x[counter]);` because java is not `pass-by-referenced` so if you add element in `add` function it wouldn't effect on your `result` variable.

Comment: @pooyan yes, it will. `result` will be mutated

Comment: @pooyan Yes my friend, the add function works fine, i''ve already been using it, it does what it is meant to do. I just need help on my xify algorithm i'm assuming

Comment: @MSK but you said that your problem is ` it appears my method just returns an empty list` and not about algorithm.

Comment: Show the code that call `xify`. I suspect you have a field you're using for the result, but you're not assigning whats returned from the call, so it stays empty.

Comment: @Bohemian Simply in main i do System.out.println(xify(array)); //this gives like an address 
       System.out.println(toString(xify(array)));// this is a helper function that works, but it displays an empty list basically

Comment: There's your problem, but post code into question please

Comment: @MSK i think your code would result `[4 3 2 1 2 1 3 2 1]` for `[4 2 3]` instead of `[4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3]`.

Comment: It outputs: http://image.prntscr.com/image/7b81868898324a0dacfd2dcc97b33d16.png why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In your main code you call your method twice, but your method is **destructive**:

```
x[counter]=x[counter]-1;
```

After the call, your array contains all zeros. So the second call will (correctly) produce an empty list.

The simplest "fix" is to call it once:

```
Node<Integer> result = xify(array);
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(toString(result)); // not sure what this does anyway?
```

The better fix is to not destroy what you pass in. If you destroy data like that in real life, other developers will hunt you down and burn you at the stake (figuratively speaking, of course...).

Comment: OMG! YOU GOT it :D The bad news is the algoritm still seems to be off... please see the outout produced....http://image.prntscr.com/image/7b81868898324a0dacfd2dcc97b33d16.png

Comment: @MSK that is a different question. Please ask a new one (keep the code and question as narrow as you can).

Comment: And please don't post java code as a runnable snippet: that feature only works for javascript.